# not able to return the data in the `response.json `

Tags: node.js

I'm using mongoCleint to connect to the database using node server. Able to post the data to the database and able to read back the data in `JSON.stringify(items)` but not able to return it. Problem is that `res.json(getRequest)` in not giving back any json despite 'JSON.stringify(items)` is giving me a list of items. Am I not doing it right?

```
app.get('/getItems', function (req, res) {
    var getRequest;
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
       if(err){
         console.log("there is an error")
       } else {
         console.log("running get request")
         const db = client.db(dbName);
         db.collection('documents').find({}).toArray(function(err, items) {
           if(err) { 
             console.error(err) 
           } else {
             console.log(JSON.stringify(items))
             getRequest = JSON.stringify(items)
           }
         })
         client.close();
        }
     });
   console.log(res.json(getRequest))
   return res.json({ success: true, data: getRequest });
})
```

Comment: Are you using express.js?

Comment: Why do you stringify `items` before sending it with `res.json`? `res.json` accepts proper JSON and already stringifies it implicitly. Also, by using `res.json` in `console.log` and then in return, you attempt to send it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callbacks run asynchronously but you don't wait for them. Consider running the following code:

```
app.get('/getItems', async function (req, res) {

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url)

    const db = client.db(dbName)
    const getRequest = await db.collection('documents').find({}).toArray()

    client.close()
    return res.json({ success: true, data: getRequest })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment  @Cider 's response but I don't have enough points.. I think it's ok but is lacking the res.json so It won't return anything.

I'd do it this way:

```
app.get('/getItems', async function (req, res) {

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(url)

    const db = client.db(dbName)
    const getRequest = await db.collection('documents').find({}).toArray()

    client.close()
    return res.json({ success: true, data: getRequest })
})
```